# After successfully download pdf from the firebase I can not find the pdf on the download folder in my real device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using DownloadManger (DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) to download pdf from the firebase. And I can download it throw the recyclerView adapter. When I test on my emulator it's showing on my emulator Download directory. But in a real device after complete downloading, I can't find in the download directory.

here is my code.

```
        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);
        request.setDescription("Downloading");
        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    }
```

```
holder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadFile(holder.title.getContext(),movieList.get(position).getBooksName(),".pdf",DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,movieList.get(position).getUrl());
            }
        });

permission
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanks

**I fixed my problem**
the problem was It is working on targatedDevice 28 or below but not Working on tagatedDevice 29.

Now how can I fix my problem to work on version 29?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Where-will-files-downloaded-from-playstore-be-stored ?

Comment: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);` Please tell full path. Then tell where you searched. Also tell how you searched. What did you use to search?

Comment: You do not need the read and write permission for the directory you downloaded to.

Comment: Did you post the code for function dowloadFile()?

Comment: hey thanks, I solved my problem. But its work only targetedVersion 28 or below. I was testing my device with android 10. Now I am stuck again to thinking why isn't working or targetedVersion 29.

Answer (score 0):

apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage.

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)